# WordAPI 1.1 and 1.2 usage in Apps for Office

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, word-web-addins

My customer has developed an Office app that uses WordAPI 1.1 and 1.2 calls in the code. They run the following function to perform the check on WordAPI:

```
function TestWordAPI() {

if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.1)) {
    WriteResponse('word api 1.1 supported.');
}
else
{
    WriteResponse('word api 1.1 is not supported.');
}

if (Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('WordApi', 1.2)) {
    WriteResponse('word api 1.2 supported.');
}
else
{
    WriteResponse('word api 1.2 is not supported.');
}
}
```

When they deployed the app in Desktop Word client it worked fine. They have SharePoint 2016 onprem with Office online server.
They also deployed the same app in SharePoint. The app gives different results in Office online and normal Office client.

In Office online, they see `word api 1.1 is not supported." and "word api 1.2 is not supported`

In Office client, they see `word api 1.1 is supported." and "word api 1.2 is supported.`

However, when we tested the app in our latest current channel build which is newer than documented "December 2015 update, Version 1601 (Build 6568.1000) or later" in https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/word-api-requirement-sets 
we see that it is not supported both for 1.1 and 1.2.

Also, the customer has Office online server Version 1608 (Build 7601.6800) as documented.

Please help me, if there is any other dependency which we might be missing here.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with our requirement verification but its fixed now and we already test it in OneDrive for Business and consumer and its working as expected. please give it another try and let us know if you still see the issue.

Comment: I just tested the code in OneDrive for Business and found that it is not supported. Am I missing something in the code?

Comment: i am assuming this is an OnPrem environment, right? Did you tried it in SPO?

Comment: Yes, the customer environment is SP Onprem, since we are facing some issues in setting up the exact onprem environment of the customer at our end, we tested it in Once drive for Business. Do you want me to test it in SPO? I can try that